# OpenCV - error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_stitching248d.lib'

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed OpecCV and I defined it in my project.

I try to run the code from this example:
https://github.com/bsdnoobz/opencv-code/blob/master/watershed.cpp

and i'm get this error:
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_stitching248d.lib'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGiTG.jpg)

Comment: How can i fix this problem?

Comment: what platform, what IDE ?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit
Visual Studio 2012
opencv-3.1.0

Comment: you put opencv_stitching248d.lib in the 'Input', right? but are you sure it is in the folder you are linking to?

Comment: I mean is the file opencv_stitching248d.lib exist on your hard-disk?

Comment: just a minute! you are using opencv 3 and trying to link file from 2.4.8?

Comment: I do not have stitching248d.lib in opencv folder

Comment: So you are linking to an imaginary library :) you have to find it and put it the folder. Note that stitching248d.lib is a contribution to the OpenCV library so it is not coming with the original library, you have to bring it by yourself

Comment: I do not have this file on your hard drive
I downloaded OpenCV-3.1.0
What OpenCV I have to download so I can run this code?

Comment: Where can I get the file Stitching248d.lib?

Comment: I do not know really. However, you are using OpenCV 3 why you want to link a 248 version ??

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/reg

Comment: this is the right module for you that is comptiitable with OpenCV 3

Comment: Download it and build it and get your suitable libs

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't understand what i need to download from github and where i need to put it

Comment: Ok let us take step by step.. do you have the cope of opencv 3 or you just us it as libs ?

Comment: http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/ this is a tutorail about how to use the new registeration (sitching) module. and I can provide you with opencv 3 x86 lib opencv_stitching300.lib ? does this solve your problem

Comment: i just download
http://opencv.org/downloads.html
opencv-3.1.0
and install it, and than i open project in visual studio and define OpenCV
from this Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w

Comment: Ok it seems that you are not building your own binaries you have just download them. it is ok.  see my above comment

Comment: now i think i Understand the problem, the video is 2.4.8 and i install 3.1

Comment: but in this link
http://opencv.org/downloads.html
there is no OpenCV 2.4.8

Comment: Ok, i Understand what the problem, in Project properties on visual studio i write like the vidieo, 2.4.9 and i use in opencv-3.1.0 and i  need to write The correct settings of 3.1.0 or 2.4.9 as it recorded a video

Comment: yes sth like this. I recomended to depend on one and only one version

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now can I put all the settings to the correct version OpenCV-3.1.0 and will update you if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`opencv_stitching248d.lib` is a contribution to the OpenCV library. You have to download this module by yourself and add its .lib and .dll( if you are dynamically linking).

The error you are getting is just because there is not `opencv_stitching248d.lib` file on your machine